# How to run a cmd command in the current Terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple issue involding child_proccess. If you call child_process from a script its going to run that command in that script. If you export a function that runs the command, for what i've tested, it tries to run the command in the library terminal and not the current terminal.
Example:
Lets say you have your script `a.js` that you export to `b.js` and in `a.js` you have this function called `hello` that prints "Hello World" with the echo command:

```js
//a.js
export function hello(){
  child_process.execSync("echo Hello World");
}
```

```js
import {hello} from "a.js"
hello();
```

When you run it it will not send you anything. If you print "Hello World" with console.log() it will return it in the current terminal. Is there a way to execute a `cmd` command in the current terminal?

Answer (score 0):

The command is actually running on the same terminal. Since you have not asked the `child_process` to direct the `stdout` to the current terminal, it does not print anything.

```
//a.js
export function hello(){
  child_process.execSync("echo Hello World",{stdio:"inherit"});
}
```

This should work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much. Really my question was how do i use the options. Thank you so much for clarifying everything!